# How to SSR with Next.js, Apollo Client, and MongoDB Atlas GraphQL API

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

From my Next.js app ([Pages router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages)) I'm using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) to connect to a my [GraphQL API provided by MongoDB Atlas App Services](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/graphql/). I'm following [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/nextjs/#server-side-rendering) in the MongoDB docs and am attempting to [server-side render](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/server-side-rendering) (SSR) the results from the API response.

Although I've followed the guide largely verbatim in a [new project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nistp?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.js) (only swapping out the GraphQL API used along with the App ID) I can't get SSR to work. I keep getting back a 401 (unauthorised response) saying the access token has expired in the console:

```
statusCode: 401,
result: {
  error: 'invalid session: access token expired',
  error_code: 'InvalidSession',
}
```

From the MongoDB logs I see the following error:

```
Error: unauthorized
Logs: ["token contains an invalid number of segments"]
```

In my browser console I can see that the cookie is created:
[image]

My Next.js `index.js` page (with SSR):

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import * as Realm from 'realm-web';
import nookies from 'nookies';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink, gql } from '@apollo/client';

// 2. Function to create GraphQL client
const createClient = (token) =>
    new ApolloClient({
        link: new HttpLink({
            ssrMode: true,
            uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });

// 3. GraphQL Query used in SSR
const GET_PROPERTIES = gql`
    query GetProperties {
        properties {
            title
        }
    }
`;

// 4. Server-side logic to parse cookie and run query
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { accessToken } = nookies.get(context);
    const client = createClient(accessToken);

    // Deconstruct `data` from the query response
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: GET_PROPERTIES,
    });

    return {
        props: { properties: data.properties },
    };
}

// Full page exported that gets the data from SSR
export default function ServerPage({ properties }) {
    const app = useApp();
    // note: useEffect runs in the browser but does not run during server-side rendering
    useEffect(() => {
        // If no logged in user, log in
        if (app && !app.currentUser) {
            const anonymousUser = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
            app.logIn(anonymousUser);
        }
    }, [app, app?.currentUser]);

    return (
        <main className="bg-slate-100 flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-3/6">
                <div className="flex justify-center mt-10 mb-6">
                    <h2 className="inline-block text-center text-2xl sm:text-3xl font-extrabold text-slate-900 tracking-tight">
                        Server-Side Propertiers
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {properties ? (
                            properties.map((property) => (
                                <li
                                    key="math.random()"
                                    className="bg-white rounded-md border border-slate-200/75 my-2 p-4 leading-normal"
                                >
                                    {property.title}
                                </li>
                            ))
                        ) : (
                            <p>None found</p>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

The only thing I've added in addition to [the guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/nextjs/#server-side-render-the-data) is the `useEffect` to actually log the user in. It seemed to me this was missing but the result is the same either way, with or without the `useEffect`.

`_app.js`:

```js
import '@/styles/globals.css';

import { useApp } from '@/hooks/useApp';
import { setCookie } from 'nookies';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const app = useApp();

    // Reset the user access token in cookies on a regular interval
    useEffect(() => {
        const user = app?.currentUser;
        if (user) {
            setCookie(null, 'accessToken', user.accessToken);
            // Refresh token before session expires
            const TWENTY_MIN_MS = 1200000;
            const resetAccessToken = setInterval(async () => {
                await app?.currentUser?.refreshCustomData();
                setCookie(null, 'accessToken', user.accessToken);
            }, TWENTY_MIN_MS);
            // Clear interval setting access token whenever component unmounts or
            // there's a change in user.
            return () => clearInterval(resetAccessToken);
        }
    }, [app, app?.currentUser]);

    return (
        <>
            <Component {...pageProps} app={app} />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

`hooks/useApp.js` simply retrieves the Atlas app ID:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as Realm from 'realm-web';
export function useApp() {
    const [app, setApp] = useState(null);
    // Run in useEffect so that App is not created in server-side environment
    useEffect(() => {
        setApp(Realm.getApp(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID));
    }, []);
    return app;
}
```

I've also setup a [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5nistp?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.js) to show it in full (although .env variables would need to be replaced).

To clarify, I'm trying to authenticate with MongoDB Atlas App Services using [anonymous authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/anonymous/) via the [Realm Web SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/) (which [supports all Next.js rendering modes including CSR, SSR, and SSG](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/nextjs/)). I'm using Apollo Client to make the GraphQL request and then I want to render the response server-side.

I can also confirm that I have enabled anonymous authentication on my API and I can successfully make the request using the same App ID and endpoint via Postman. The response comes back fine.

Is there anything I am missing?